# css postion:fixed not working

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I've a div element `<div class="getBack">Get back to portfolio!</div>`

and some css

`.getBack{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}`

And for some reason, this position fixed doesn't work and I don't know why.
It just scrolls up, out of sight

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/amrnwx9e/

Answer (score -1):

You might need to set an actual position like `top: 0; right: 0;`.  Also, make sure the parent element you want `.getBack` to be fixed relative to has a `position` other than `static`.

Comment: You are half correct.  The missing `left` and `top` and/or `bottom` and `right` attributes are likely causing some issue.  However, for `position: fixed` you don't need a parent element to be `position` other than `static`.  Fixed is relative to the viewport.  Having a non-static parent is only necessary for `position: absolute` elements.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Ah yes, you're right.  I don't use `position: fixed` a lot but am used to `absolute`.  See [position - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)